# expo eas build failing Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I am building eas build and its failing after some time by showing this error

- What went wrong:
  [stderr]
  Execution failed for task ':expo-intent-launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
  [stderr]

> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
> [stderr]

- Try:
  [stderr]
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  [stderr]
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

And when I add that library by yarn add expo-intent-launcher@specific_version then its showing build fail for next library .so is any way to find out which library will fail and ill add them before building .or any guidance on this please help thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue, Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to upgrade `expo-intent-launcher` package to version `10.2.0`
https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-intent-launcher/CHANGELOG.md#1020--2022-04-18

Details why it happens in the PR: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/16941